# VBA Importing other spreadsheets into one

Tags: vba, excel

Hello thanks for reading my question. I'm trying to import a lot of files into one workbook.

This portion of the scrip works once through the first workbook but crashes on the second workbook when it hits sheet three.

```
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    Set tmpWb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each Sheet In tmpWb.Sheets


        Range("A2").Select
        If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
            sFileName = tmpWb.Name
            sFileName = Replace(sFileName, ".xlsx", "")
            Sheet.Name = sFileName
            wbNew.Activate
            Sheet.Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(1)
        Else
            'do nothing
        End If
        tmpWb.Activate

        On Error GoTo LastSheet
            Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
 LastSheet:

    Next Sheet

    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = dir()

Loop
```

It's crashing at Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
with this error
**Run-Time error 9 Subscript out of range**

Comment: I'm guessing that's because when your active sheet is the last sheet, then there is no `ActiveSheet.Index + 1` to reference.

Comment: Lots of bugs in here. For instance, you are not explicitly setting the Active sheet anywhere (only the active workbook) so commands like `Range("A2").Select` are pretty much a crapshoot.

Comment: Good point on Range, I added tmpWb.ActiveSheet before the first Range("A2") to ensure it was selected.

Comment: Never mind the above doesn't work

Comment: But why does this work for the first workbook but always fails on the second. As is it works on the first file that I import but when it moves to the second one I chokes on the last sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Done, took a bit of time to figure it out but this functions nicely now, there maybe another bug but it can be used to import files and sheets from the files into one workbook

```
Sub GetSheets()
Dim sFileName As String
Dim Path As String
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim tmpWb As Workbook
Dim tSheets As Long
Dim iSheets As Long
    iSheets = 0
    Set wbNew = gWrkBook() 'creat new workbook

    Path = gGetFolder("Any default folder path")
    If gSearch(Path, "\", "LastChar") > 0 Then
        Path = Path + "\"
    End If
    Filename = dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        Set tmpWb = ActiveWorkbook
        tSheets = tmpWb.Worksheets.Count

        If tSheets > 0 Then
            iSheets = 1
            tmpWb.Sheets(iSheets).Activate

            For iSheets = 1 To tSheets
                tmpWb.Sheets(iSheets).Activate
                Range("A2").Select

                If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
                    sFileName = tmpWb.Name + "-" + CStr(iSheets)
                    sFileName = Replace(sFileName, ".xlsx", "")
                    tmpWb.Sheets(iSheets).Name = sFileName
                    wbNew.Activate
                    tmpWb.Sheets(iSheets).Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(1)

                Else
                End If
                tmpWb.Activate
            Next
        End If

        Workbooks(Filename).Close savechanges:=False
        Filename = dir()

    Loop
End Sub

    Public Function gGetFolder(strPath As String) As String

Dim fldr As FileDialog

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath

        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    gGetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing

End Function
```